# how to make text area only as high as the text inside?

Tags: forms

I am using a textarea in my form api to hold dynamic text in a form and making it read only.  I am using a textarea so that it will shrink in mobile view.  the problem is there is a big space at the bottom of the text area.  how can I make the text area be only as tall as the text inside with css ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi think You need yo write a function to adjust the textarea height according to height. Can you please have look at the link http://bdadam.com/blog/automatically-adapting-the-height-textarea.html

Hope this helps...